# Context API envía una variable como undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, context

Estoy usando Context API para manejar la autenticación de usuario.

Hay algo raro porque tengo una variable **admin** que si tiene valor en el componente UserContext, pero cuando la llevo al App y la recibe como undefined. Imprimí por consola y desde UserContext.js, aparece el string Admin. Pero cuando lo envío a App, este pasa a ser undefined.

Así muestra consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código completo del componente UserContext es:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

export const UserContext = createContext({});

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [logged, setLogged] = useState(false);
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const userStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");

  const login = (data) => {
    setUser(data);
    setLogged(true);
    console.log(data.role);
    checkRole(data.role);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
    setUser(null);
    setAdmin(false);
    Swal.fire("User session closed", "", "success");
  };

  const checkUser = () => {
    if (userStorage) {
      setLogged(true);
      console.log("There is a user logged in");
    } else {
      console.log("No user logged in");
    }
  };

  const checkRole = (user) => {
    if (user) {
      if (user === "Admin") {
        setAdmin(user);
        console.log("Is admin user");
      } else {
        console.log("Is regular user");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("I can't check the role");
    }
  };

  console.log(admin);

  return (
    <div>
      <UserContext.Provider
        value={{ checkUser, user, admin, login, logged, setLogged, logout }}
      >
        {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserProvider;
```

Y el de App.js:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/common/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Footer from "./components/common/Footer";
import Details from "./components/Details";
import Dashboard from "./Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Error404 from "./components/Error404";
import UserProvider, { UserContext } from "./Context/UserContext";

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState();
  const { admin } = useContext(UserContext);

  const consultMovies = async () => {
    await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_MOVIES)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setMovies(data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    consultMovies();
  }, []);

  console.log({ admin });

  return (
    <div>
      <UserProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home movies={movies} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/login">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/signup">
              <SignUp />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/details/:id">
              <Details />
            </Route>
            {/* <Route
              exact
              path="/dashboard"
              render={() => {
                return admin === "Admin" ? (
                  <Dashboard consultMovies={consultMovies} movies={movies} />
                ) : (
                  <Redirect to="/"></Redirect>
                );
              }}
            ></Route> */}
            <Route exact path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard consultMovies={consultMovies} movies={movies} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="*">
              <Error404 />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </UserProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Alguien sabe por qué podrá ser que el valor está llegando como undefined al App? Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Comparte el código de todo el `UserContext`, saludos

Comment: Agregado el código completo de UserContext

Comment: Bien, asumo que estas importando ambas funciones del contexto en `App`, tanto `UserContext` como `UserProvider`; Ahora,  hay un detalle con el `import` de `UserContext`, pero antes ¿Estas usando el `UserProvider` en `App`? y de ser así ¿Cómo lo estas usando? Si pudieras subir esa pieza de código también, Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de leer este problema, es para un proyecto para aplicar a un trabajo. Agregué el código completo del App, donde muestro como al UserProvider, hago que envuelva al resto de los componentes.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución. El Proveedor no estaba encerrando al App, por ende este último seguía siendo su padre y no podía recibir la información